# autoref not adding "scheme", when converting .eps with auto-pst-pdf

Tags: hyperref, auto-pst-pdf, chemstyle

### Problem/Question

I'm encountering problem using `\autoref` (from `hyperref` package) to reference a `scheme`-environment (provided `chemstyle` package), when using `\includegraphics[*]{*.eps}` (working with `auto-pst-pdf` package), as it will omitt "Scheme" in the typesetted reference.

Is this an known issue, and is there any way to bypass this problem?

I already tried to use

```
  \def\schemeautorefname{Scheme}
```

in preamble - without any succes.

### M(N)WE

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage[runs=2,crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\RequirePackage[varioref=false]{chemstyle}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
%usage on an .eps file
\begin{scheme}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Caption}
    \includegraphics{./EPS.eps}
    \label{schm:test1}
\end{scheme}
Test \autoref{schm:test1}... (Not working)
%usage on an .png file
\begin{scheme}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Caption}
    \includegraphics{../PNG.png}
    \label{schm:test2}
\end{scheme}
Test \autoref{schm:test2}... (Working)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have put `\label` *after* `\includegraphics`. In the case of `.eps` files, package `auto-pst-pdf` sets an anchor (`pspicture.1`) for the graphics. This anchor (`pspicture.1`) is then used by `\label` instead of the anchor set by the `\caption` (`scheme.caption.1`).

Solution: `\label` belongs right after `\caption`:

```
\begin{scheme}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{schm:test1}
    \includegraphics{./EPS.eps}
\end{scheme}

\begin{scheme}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{schm:test2}
    \includegraphics{../PNG.png}
\end{scheme}
```

Comment: ...working like a charm!! Thank you very very much, I'd never had thought about that :)

So it's recomended, or even needed to have `\label` directly after `\caption`? Is there a convention (or does it make a difference) to put this block before or after the `\includegraphics` command?

Comment: @lcnittl: Often captions go below figures and above tables.